# Check validation with id's and assign custom errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(I am not using Jquery Validation)

I'm trying to return custom errors if the field is incorrect or empty. For instance, if the `#id_first_name` field is null. Append the string, " first name" to `p#error` to result in :

```
Please fill in your first name
```

I've made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8YgNT/14/) to show what I mean. So in the list of required fields... How would I be able to grab / check each individual required id and assign the corrosponding error?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fiddle should be as basic as possible, removing all other information, but you could try something like this,

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
   $('input').each(function(){
      $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == 'null')
      {
         $('p#error').append('Please enter your ' + $this.attr('placeholder'));
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Worked! `$this.attr('placeholder')` was a great idea especially when looping through. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below

```
$('form input').on('blur', function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var val = $(this).val();
     if(id == 'myInput') {
          if(!val.length) {
              $('#error').append('Please enter a value into the input');
          }
     }
});
```

This is a simple way of doing form validation, just tailor the example to your needs.

**EDIT**

If you want it to work in your example it would be better to have a `div` with the id of `error` and append `p` tags with the corresponding error values.

Happy coding :)